# Apply filter before or after Downsampling?

Tags: filters, audio, downsampling, resampling

**Context:** I'm trying to do formant estimation. My first attempt didn't work out all that well so I'm trying to follow closely [Praat](https://github.com/praat/praat/) since their formant estimation is remarkably accurate.

**Question:** I thought it was obvious to apply the filter (pre-emphasis) before Downsampling, however Praat doesn't. Is there a reason for this? Are filters usually applied before or after downsampling?

Comment: what's Praat ? You should add some info.

Comment: Have you tried [asking the authors](https://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/)?

Comment: Okay, I'll try asking Paul sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the reference yet , but just to answer the question, yes filtering is performed prior to down sampling to avoid aliasing back in the out of band signals. However if your signal is already appropriately bandlimited you could forego the filter entirely. There's various reasons you might want to do other, unrelated, filtering after the downsampling operation. In fact, doing such filtering after the downsampler is preferable due to the lower sample rate and thus lower computational complexity.